# Syntax error in formula

Tags: vba, excel, formula

Could you please help me to identify and fix the error I am facing in the following program. It's saying syntax error and I tried all the possible ways to enter the formula but I couldn't.

```
Dim T As Integer 
T = 12
Range("AJ3").Value = "Target ETY"
Range("AJ4").Formula = "=SUM(((Range("A4").Value) * aa), (Range("C4").Value * b), (Range("E4").Value * c), (Range("G4").Value * d), (Range("I4").Value * e), (Range("K4").Value * f), (Range("M4").Value * g), (Range("O4").Value * h), (Range("Q4").Value * i), (Range("S4").Value * j), (Range("U4").Value * k), (Range("W4").Value * l), (Range("Y4").Value * m), (Range("AA4").Value * n), (Range("AC4").Value * o), (Range("AE4").Value * p))"
Range("AJ4").Select
Range("AK3").Value = "Actual ETY"
Range("AK4").FormulaR1C1 = Sum((Range("B4").Value * aa), (Range("D4").Value * b), (Range("F4").Value * c), (Range("H4").Value * d), (Range("J4").Value * e), (Range("L4").Value * f), (Range("N4").Value * g), (Range("P4").Value * h), (Range("R4").Value * i), (Range("T4").Value * j), (Range("V4").Value * k), (Range("X4").Value * l), (Range("Z4").Value * m), (Range("AB4").Value * n), (Range("AD4").Value * o), (Range("AF4").Value * p))
Range("AK4").Select
Range("AL4").Value = Range("AK4").Value / T
Range("AL4").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "0.0%"
Range("AL3").Value = "Total ETY"
MsgBox "Total ETY for Day" & vbNewLine & Range("AL4").Value
If Range("AL4").Value >= 0 Then
UserForm2.Show
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: I am trying to put a formula in the cell AJ4 where it has number of operations included in it (addition and multiplication) but I am unable to get the result as per manual calculations. It is identifying the Range("A4").value as syntax error

Comment: nope its not working, any other way please

Comment: The syntax error is caused by invalid strings: `"=SUM(((Range("A4").Value)...`. You concatenate multiple strings with the "&" operator: `"=SUM(((Range(" & A4 & ").Value)...`; but I think you want either `"=SUM(((" & Range(A4).Value & ")...` or `"=SUM(((Range(A4).Value)...` (all in one string)

Comment: what is the best solution for this?

Comment: If you want VBA to fill in formulas with double quotes within, you need to add another one. However seems not applicaple to you here (assuming aa/b/c/d/etc are named cells `Range("AJ4").Formula = "=SUM((A4 * aa), (C4 * b), (E4 * c), (G4 * d), (I4 * e), (K4 * f), (M4 * g), (O4 * h), (Q4 * i), (S4 * j), (U4 * k), (W4 * l), (Y4 * m), (AA4 * n), (AC4 * o), (AE4 * p))"`

Answer (score 1):

Try the changes bellow

---

```
    Dim T As Integer, frm As String
    T = 12

    Range("AJ3").Value = "Target ETY"

    frm = "=Sum(A4 * " & aa & ", C4 * " & b & ", E4 * " & c & ", G4 * " & d & ", "
    frm = frm & "I4 * " & e & ", K4 * " & f & ", M4 * " & g & ", O4 * " & h & ", "
    frm = frm & "Q4 * " & i & ", S4 * " & j & ", U4 * " & k & ", W4 * " & l & ", "
    frm = frm & "Y4 * " & m & ", AA4 * " & n & ", AC4 * " & o & ", AE4 * " & p & ")"
    Range("AJ4").Formula = frm

    Range("AK3").Value = "Actual ETY"

    frm = "=Sum(B4 * " & aa & ", D4 * " & b & ", F4 * " & c & ", H4 * " & d & ", "
    frm = frm & "J4 * " & e & ", L4 * " & f & ", N4 * " & g & ", P4 * " & h & ", "
    frm = frm & "R4 * " & i & ", T4 * " & j & ", V4 * " & k & ", X4 * " & l & ", "
    frm = frm & "Z4 * " & m & ", AB4 * " & n & ", AD4 * " & o & ", AF4 * " & p & ")"
    Range("AK4").Formula = frm

    Range("AL4").Value = Range("AK4").Value / T
    Range("AJ4, AK4, AL4").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    Range("AL3").Value = "Total ETY"

    MsgBox "Total ETY for Day" & vbNewLine & Range("AL4").Value

    If Range("AL4").Value >= 0 Then UserForm2.Show
End Sub
```

---

(I'm not sure what aa, b, c, ... are because your code is incomplete, but I think they're variables that you want to use in your formula?)

Comment: You missed deleting one of the `Select` statements (`Range("AJ4").Select`).  (P.S. I'm glad you had the patience to go through and rewrite those formulae! +1)

Comment: Thank you very much - It worked